# selecting row using wpdb which contain special symbols

Tags: wpdb

I got a table with one of the column have special charaters. I inserted to the table as

```
$sql=$wpdb->prepare( 
         "INSERT INTO `mytable`
            ( `question`, `remarks`)
        VALUES ('%s', '%s' )", 
        array(sanitize_text_field($question),sanitize_text_field($remarks)) );
$wpdb->query($sql);
```

which in turn inserted a row like this

```
-------------------------------------------------|
| question                          |   remarks  |
-------------------------------------------------|
| \"creating world \" written by?   |   chom-lu  |
|                                   |            |
-------------------------------------------------|
```

But When i try to SELECT

```
$quest='"creating world " written by?';
$sql=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE
            `question` LIKE '%s' AND `remarks` LIKE '%s'" ,
             '%'.sanitize_text_field($quest).'%');
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
```

return empty rows..

```
echo $sql; //reutrns as
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `question` LIKE '%\"creating world \" written by?%'
```

What i did wrong.. please help to find a way out of this problem.. this problem eating up my whole day from morning...

```
will you Speak in PHP... plezzzzzzzzze and IN GENERALIZED FORMAT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guys i figured out a way to do this.... Not a clean one but it just do the job for me..

```
global $wpdb;
$sql=$wpdb->prepare("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE question ='%s'",         
                      like_escape(sanitize_text_field($question)));
/*******************
actualy following do the trick for me
all SINGLE \ are replaced by \\\ 
where SINGLE slashed statement genereated by prepare()
*************************/
$sql=str_replace('\\', '\\\\\\', $sql); 
$result = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
if (empty($result))
{
    //doing some stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable` WHERE `question` = '\\\"creating world \\\" written by\?'
```

In php

```
global $wpdb;
$quest=addcslashes('\"creating world \" written by?','\"?');
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE
            question ='{$quest}'");
```

Comment: That works for single line selection.. will you speak in PHP.. PLSSSSSSSS

Comment: I mean something like addslash()....

Comment: sometimes there will some symbols that i cant predict like''(single quotes).. then..

Answer (score -2):

very good morning, try this solution,,

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 
question LIKE '%[\"creating world \" written by?]%'
```

use square bracket,,, i hope this will help you,,

thanks

Comment: that is not helping at all while WisdmLabs solution worked for me.. but i need something in php to generate something like that...

Comment: Please refer this link , i hope this link will help you,, (http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: its a dead end.. shows an " An error occured...Exception of type 'System.Web.HttpUnhandledException' was thrown."

Comment: sry , check it now,, (http://sqlserver2000.databases.aspfaq.com/how-do-i-search-for-special-characters-e-g-in-sql-server.html)

Comment: sory yar.. it may be our problem... we use mysql ...